# Prove that $\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $f: [0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous function and $$\sum_{n\geq1}f(n + x)$$ converges uniformly for $x \in [0, 1]$.

Is there any ability to prove to prove that in this case $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$$ also converges?

Here's what I think about it:

We only know that $$ \forall \varepsilon > 0 \ \exists N \ \forall n>N \ \forall x \in [0, 1] \ |S_n(x)−f(x)|< \varepsilon $$
where $$S_n(x) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} f_k(x)$$ and $$f_n(x) = f(n + x)$$
But how can we use this fact for integral convergence?
I also know that $\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ converges iff $\sum_{n\geq1}f(n)$ converges but seems like we don't know anything about $f$.

Comment: "$\int_0^{+\infty}f(x) \text d x$ converges iff $\sum_{n\geq 1}f(n)$ converges" : this is not true in general

Comment: Does it works only for non-negative functions?

Comment: It works for monotonous function. Even for non-negative uniformly continuous functions it is not true, as you can have $\int_0^{+\infty} f = +\infty$ and $f(n) = 0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; first we assume $f\geq 0,$ then deduce the general case.
When $f\geq 0,$ we can write the identity
$$\int_0^{\infty} f(x) \, dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_n^{n+1} f(x) \, dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 f(x+n) \, dx,$$
valid even when the integral is infinite thanks to non-negativity.

By Tonelli's theorem, for non-negative functions we can interchange summation and integration, to find that
$$\int_0^{\infty} f(x) \, dx = \int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(x+n) \, dx.$$

If $f$ is continuous and the partial sums converge uniformly on $[0,1],$ then the infinite sum must be continuous on $[0,1]$ (a uniform limit of the continuous partial sums is continuous). Therefore this integral is finite, as a continuous function integrated over a compact set has finite integral.

Now the general case follows by writing $f = f^+ - f^-$ into a combination of its positive and negative parts, and applying this argument to each of them individually.

Comment: Are you sure that uniform convergence of $\sum_{n} f(x+n)$ implies that of $\sum_n f^{\pm}(x+n)$ ?

Comment: Uniform convergence of the series is enough to exchange series and Riemann integral in this case, so there is no need to assume $f\geq 0$ in the first place

Comment: @SolubleFish I am very sure, because $f\mapsto f^+$ is a continuous function on the space of continuous functions, and so it preserves uniform limits.

Comment: That’s the wrong direction. The issue is that you can have f converge uniformly without $f+$ converging. For example, let $f(x)$ be $(-1)^n/n$ on $[n,n+1-1/n]$ and a straight line on the last bit to preserve continuity).

Comment: You can still show it’s true, it just requires digging into the $\epsilon$ definitions. It’s well known that uniform converge of integrals equals the integral of the limit. You can tweak that proof for when $x$ isn’t an integer using that the min/max on each range approaches 0.

Answer (score 0):

If by converge you mean integrable in a Lebesgue sense then the answer seems to be no.

Define $b:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$b(x) = \max(0, 1-2|x-{1 \over 2}|)$. Note that $b$ is continuous, the support of $b$ is $[0,1]$ and $b(x) \in [0,1]$.

Let $f(x) = \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^{k+1}{1 \over k+1}b(x-k)$. Note that for a given $x \in [0,1]$ there is at most one non zero element in the summation.

It is straightforward to check that $f$ is continuous but not $L^1$.

Let $\phi_N(x) = \sum_{n \ge 1}^N f(x+n)$, $\phi(x) = \lim_N \phi_N(x)$.

Then $\phi(x)-\phi_N(x) = \sum_{n>N} \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^{k+1}{1 \over k+1}b(x+n-k) $.

If $x \in [0,1)$ then $\phi(x)-\phi_N(x) = \sum_{n>N}  (-1)^{n+1}{1 \over n+1}b(x) $ (if $x=1$ then $\phi(x)-\phi_N(x) = 0 $) and so
$|\phi(x)-\phi_N(x) | \le |\sum_{n>N}  (-1)^{n+1}{1 \over n+1}|$. In particular, the convergence is uniform.